# I keep getting the error Condition "!is_inside_tree()" is true. Returning: Transform3D()

Tags: 3d, godot, treenode

When the player clicks I am trying to pass the position and direction of the camera3D (which is in the player scene) to the world scene through a signal to spawn a bullet with that direction and position. The world scene is a parent of the player scene and is able to get the information but only the position actually works, and if I pass position and direction for some reason it won't spawn the bullet in the right place

I tried moving the bullet node around to try to get it to work

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that the operation you are doing cannot be done on a `Node` that is not on the scene tree... Either:

- The `Node` hasn't been added yet (i.e. you haven't called `add_child` yet).
- The `Node` been removed (either because of `remove_child` or `queue_free`).

And since this is about a `Transform3D` I'm going to guess this is about reading or writing the `global_transform` of a `Node3D`.

**Note**: I'll continue talking about the `global_transform`, but this applies to `global_position`,. `global_rotation` and `global_rotation_degrees` since they are all shorthand to `global_transform` for convenience.

---

Now, setting the `global_transform` outside of the scene tree is not an error, but it sets `transform` instead (which would explain why you are getting the bullet spawned in the wrong position).

While you could address that by setting the `global_transform` *after* you added the `Node3D` to the scene tree, that might give colliders an opportunity to run before Godot sets the updated position.

So, instead I'm going to encourage to set the `transform`... Let us say:

- You have a `Node3D`, which I'll call `instance`.
- And you want `instance` placed at `desired_global_transform`.
- And added as child of `parent` which is in the scene tree.

Then you do this:

```
instance.transform = parent.global_transform.affine_inverse() * desired_global_transform
parent.add_child(instance)
```

Contrived? Yes, but I'd expect it to work around the wrong position.

The idea is that when `instance` is added as a child of `parent`, then `instance.global_transform` will be `parent.global_transform * instance.transform`... Then the `parent.global_transform` cancels out with its inverse, leaving `desired_global_transform`.

---

But getting the `global_transform` of a `Node3D` that is not in the scene tree is an error.

In this case you say you read the `global_transform` of a `Camera3D`... Which makes be believe the `Camera3D` isn't in the scene tree.

Since you say the `Camera3D` is part of the player scene, I'm guessing the whole scene is outside the scene tree.

You, of course, can use `is_inside_tree` to check, and don't run the code if it returns `false`. *If you also add a `breakpoint` there, it might help you debug the situation.*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here is how I solved it.

1. Start by making a backup of the script that brings the error OR a copy of the entire project's script.
2. Convert every ***print()*** statement in the code to a ***push_error*()**.
   This will push all printed out statements to the error output window allowing you to see which stage this error occurs at.
   For this step, you might want to reduce the ***print()*** statements so that the output isn't much.
3. Run the project and see what point the !*is_inside_tree* occurs.
   At this point you could already have an idea of how to solve the issue. If no, move on to step 4.
4. Put a breakpoint on the latest 1 or 2 lines before the !*is_inside_tree* error as seen in the error output window.
5. Run the project and run and once the breakpoint is hit, use the step into feature repeatedly until the !*is_inside_tree* error is printed.

That'll surely help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when doing:

cube_object.global_position = last_valid_position
get_parent().add_child(object)

fix was to change the global_position after calling .add_child()

get_parent().add_child(object)
cube_object.global_position = last_valid_position